# Prevent access to public webpack bundle? ExpressJS

Tags: express, webpack

In my webpack config I have the publicPath set like so:

```
publicPath: '/js'
```

This way it points to `public/js`. Also in my `index.pug` file, which is loaded by the server and not in the `public` folder I have this:

```
extends layout

block content
  main#app
  script(src="/js/bundle.js")
```

Unfortunately, this enables people accessing my site to visit `example.com/js/bundle.js`. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/js/bundle.js` is a script file you are using in your web page, then there is NO way to prevent the browser from going directly to `http://example.com/js/bundle.js`.  That's the exact URL that the browser uses to load the script from your web page so that URL has to work.

ALL Javascript that runs in your web page is openly available to the public.  You cannot change that.  That's the architecture of the web and browsers.

> Unfortunately, this enables people accessing my site to visit example.com/js/bundle.js. Is there a way to prevent this?

No.  You cannot prevent it.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any recommended ways to obfuscate the bundle file name without hardcoding it? Eg. `example.com/js/e2e3bbiefqic-bundle.js`

Comment: @MattHough - I don't know what you mean "without hard coding it".

Comment: I mean without just naming the file `e2e3bbiefqic-bundle.js` myself and not providing a reference to everything else that uses it. Is there a way to give everything a reference to an obscure bundle.js file name.

Probably a way to automatically change it often would be nice. I was looking for a module that did that but couldn't find any.

Comment: @MattHough - There's just really no reason to do that.  Anyone who wants to can just look in the page and see what the script file's current name is and then just download it.  It's not really worth it to find a way to automatically change the name.  Anyone who wants to see it can see it.  There are tools to obfuscate the JS itself if you feel that would help you, but all that really does is slow a determined hacker down a little bit as they can still get access to the code and even run it through some unobfuscate tools.

Comment: @MattHough - It's just a fact that client-side Javascript is publicly viewable.  If you want to protect some algorithm or something like that, put that code on the server and use an ajax call to call it.  That's the only way to actually protect the code from viewing.

Comment: It's already obfuscated, it's more for cleanliness than anything. I will just give it a long name. Thanks.